# Magento backup without maintenance mode

Tags: magento2

I am new Magento 2 I was wondering if it is possible to take backup of magento without putting it in maintenance mode? (it's a client requirement since they do it daily.)

thanks in advance :)

Kind Regards
Sajid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup backup using back office.

Stores=> Configuration=> Advanced=> System=>Scheduled Backup Settings and set without maintenance mode.